# what does mac os /Library folder store?

Tags: macos

I am a new to mac osx. One thing confusing me is what does `/Library` or `/System/Library` folders store? As its name meaning, I thought is should be something like `/lib` or `/usr/lib` in Linux. However, it does not. Inside it, it looks more similar to application bundles. And all naming is very application-specific, like `/Library/iChat`. If they are application-specific, then why they are called `Library`? Usually when named as `Library`, it is for codes or resources sharing purpose.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The library folders store settings, resources, and support files. There up to 6 "levels" of them:

- The user library, ~/Library, stores per-user settings etc.
- The local library, /Library, stores computer-wide settings etc. BTW, I call this the "local" library, because in NextStep it was /Local/Library, but you'll see all sorts of other names for it, such as the root library, computer library, ...
- The network library, /Network/Library would store settings shared by all computers in a network domain -- if a network domain admin set one up, which nobody does anymore
- The system library, /System/Library, stores the base settings, resources, etc that come with OS X. In theory, you shouldn't change anything in here.

Sandboxed apps don't have access to most of the user's home folder. They're mostly restricted to their own sandbox "container" (which is itself inside the user library), and as a result they get their own "private" libraries:

- Per-application sandbox libraries, ~/Library/Containers/<application-ID>/Data/Library, which will generally contain a few real folders like Preferences and Saved Application State, and also symbolic links to the regular-user-library versions of other folders (e.g. Fonts).
- Application group sandbox libraries, ~/Library/Group Containers/<application-group-ID>/Library, is used to store shared preferences, application support files, caches, etc between related groups of applications (from the same developer).

Now, as for the files inside the various library folders: Most of them are organized by type (e.g. there's a Preferences folder, a Caches folder, an Application Support folder, etc) with files/subfolders per application (or system component, or whatever). Some resource types are available to many or all programs (e.g. Fonts, Keychains, Services), so there's just a bunch of files there. However, some programs (mostly Apple-authored ones) are, um, egotistical enough to think they need their own top-level folder inside the library, so they go ahead and create one and store things in it.

As for the name "Library", I wouldn't read too much into it. It's basically a place to store things that programs need to get at, but that the user doesn't (generally) need to be explicitly aware of. Basically, things that the user never needs to double-click or use an open/save dialog to access. When you run Mail.app, you don't need to tell it to use the settings in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist, or the cached mailbox contents in ~/Library/Mail, or the state information in ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState.

Comment: @Gordon, Re "which nobody does anymore"; elaborate?

Comment: I don't see how is `/Library` any different from `/System/Library`

Comment: From what it sounds like, they are similar in that they are read by everyone on the machine, but a big difference comes from [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), which restricts write access to everything in /System.  Meaning if you wanted to change the definition for something /System/Library, you would copy it to /Library and edit it from there.

Comment: what's exactly `~/Library/Application Support`?

Comment: @baggiponte It's sort of a catchall location for applications to store things they need that don't fit into any of the categories that have their own Library subfolders (e.g. Preferences, Caches, Saved Application State, etc). Generally, each app that needs to use it should create its own subfolder (e.g. BBEdit.app creates ~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/) and store whatever it needs to inside.

Comment: can someone provide an official link about this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things stored in the library seem to be the audiobook files for the books app.

/Users/Richard/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books/Audiobooks

Annoyingly each book is contained within its own folder with a nice user friendly name such as: "sha1-4ab87686f123fa18d99d627569b909daad8cf1b5"