# Where to find sshd logs on MacOS sierra

Tags: macos, logging, sshd

I want to install Pseudo-Distributed HBase environment on my Mac OS Sierra (10.12.4), and it requires ssh installed and can log with `ssh localhost` without password. But sometimes I came across with error when I use `ssh` to log in. Above all are question background, and the actual question is where can I find debug logs of `sshd` so I could know why logging is failed in further?

As I know, Mac OS already have `sshd` installed and use `launchd` to manage it, and I know one way to output debug logs by `sshd -E /var/log/sshd.log`, but when I reviewed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration and there are two lines:

```
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO
```

I guess these two lines are used to config debug mode, then I removed `#` before them and set `LogLevel` to `DEBUG3` and then restarted `sshd`:

```
$ launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
$ launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

And then I set log path in `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
auth.*<tab>/var/log/sshd.log
```

`<tab>` means tab character here, and reloaded the config:

```
$ killall -HUP syslogd
```

But `sshd.log` file can not be found in `/var/log` folder when I executed `ssh localhost`. I also tried config the `/etc/asl.log`:

```
> /var/log/sshd.log format=raw
? [= Facility auth] file sshd.log
```

And the result was the same, can someone help me?

Answer (score 32):

Apple, as usual, decided to re-invent the wheel.

**In super-user window**

```
# log config --mode "level:debug" --subsystem com.openssh.sshd
# log  stream --level debug  2>&1 | tee /tmp/logs.out
```

**In another window**

```
$ ssh localhost
$ exit
```

**Back in Super-user window**

```
^C (interrupt)
# grep sshd /tmp/logs.out
2019-01-11 08:53:38.991639-0500 0x17faa85  Debug       0x0                  37284  sshd: (libsystem_network.dylib) sa_dst_compare_internal <private>@0 < <private>@0
2019-01-11 08:53:38.992451-0500 0xb47b5b   Debug       0x0                  57066  socketfilterfw: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:unixio] open(/usr/sbin/sshd,0x0,0x1b6) = 12
...
...
```

**In super-user window, restore default sshd logging**

```
# log config --mode "level:default" --subsystem com.openssh.sshd
```

Answer (score 11):

You can find it in /var/log/system.log. Better if you filter by "sshd":

```
cat /var/log/system.log | grep sshd
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

**cp /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist**

Then

**vi  /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist**

And add your -E  as shown below

```
 <array>
                    <string>/usr/sbin/sshd</string>
                    <string>-i</string>
                    <string>-E</string>
                    <string>/var/log/system.log</string> 
 </array>
```

And lastly restart sshd   now you will see sshd logs in /var/log/system.log

**launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist && launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist**

Comment: Why not simply modify the /System plist instead of making a new /Library one?

Comment: Edit: See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290124/6100005)

Answer (score 3):

I also had an ssh issue that I wanted to debug further and was not able to figure out how to get the sshd debug logs to appear in any of the usual places. I resorted to editing the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` file to add a `-E <log file location>` parameter (/tmp/sshd.log, for example). I also edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to change the LogLevel.  With these changes, I was able to view the more verbose logs in the specified log file.

I don't have much experience with MacOS so I'm sure there is a more correct way to configure this, but for lack of a better approach this got the logs I was looking for.

Comment: Note that on macOS 10.11 and later, changing anything underneath `/System` requires disabling [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) ([Apple Docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)); see e.g. [here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x) for how to disable it. Be careful!

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's [developer website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging), logging behavior has changed in macOS 10.12 and up:

> ### Important:
>
> Unified logging is available in iOS 10.0 and later, macOS 10.12 and later, tvOS 10.0 and later, and watchOS 3.0 and later, and supersedes ASL (Apple System Logger) and the Syslog APIs. Historically, log messages were written to specific locations on disk, such as /etc/system.log. The unified logging system stores messages in memory and in a data store, rather than writing to text-based log files.

Unfortunately, unless someone comes up with a pretty clever way to extract the log entries from memory or this mysterious "data store", I think we're SOL :/

Comment: There's the standard CLI tool named "log" which cleverly shows the misterious log.

Answer (score 1):

There is some sshd log in

/var/log/system.log

for example

`Apr 26 19:00:11 mac-de-mamie com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.7AAF2A76-3475-4D2A-9EEC-B9624143F2C2[535]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1`

Not very instructive.  I doubt if more can be obtained.  `LogLevel VERBOSE` and `LogLevel DEBUG3` in sshd_config do not help.

According to man sshd_config :
"Logging with a DEBUG level violates the privacy of users and is not recommended."

By the way, I relaunched sshd not with launchctl but with System preference Sharing, ticking Remote login.

There, I noticed the option : Allow access for ...

I suspect this settings to be OUTSIDE /etc/ssh/sshd_config
(easy to check but I have no time).

Beware that Mac OS X is not Unix : Apple developpers can do many strange things behind the scene without any care for us command line users.