# launch daemon won't load from Bash script but will from terminal

Tags: bash, macos, launchd, launchctl

I have this line inside a post install Bash script file which runs from within a PKG installer:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.myapp.plist
```

The PKG correctly installs both the job plist file and the applet which the job calls.

But when I check if the job is loaded in terminal, I get nothing returned by this:

```
launchctl list | grep mycompany
```

If I execute the same load command in Terminal, the job is loaded as expected.

Why does the job not get loaded when the script runs?

Comment: When you run `launchctl list` as a normal user, it lists Launch *Agents* running in your user session; to list Launch *Daemons*, run it as root (i.e. `sudo launchctl list`). BTW, `launchctl load` works the same way; if you run it as a normal user, it loads the job as an Agent, but if you run it as root it'll load it as a Daemon. Your package is presumably running its scripts as root (which is what you want), but it can depend on exactly how the package is configured.

Comment: OMG. Light bulb moment @GordonDavisson! If you paste that as the answer I'll mark it as such. Thank you so much. I've been staring at this for a day now as a Office Win dev!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `launchctl list` as a normal user, it lists Launch *Agents* running in your user session; to list Launch *Daemons*, run it as root (i.e. `sudo launchctl list`).

More details: some of the `launchctl` subcommands allow you to explicitly specify which domain you want to deal with. For example:

```
launchctl print system      # Prints Launch *Daemons*
launchctl print user/501    # Prints Launch *Agents* for user #501's session
```

But the older "legacy" subcommands, like `list`, `load`, `unload`, `start`, `stop`, etc predate this convention and use the user ID the command runs as to determine the domain to act on. So for example:

```
launchctl load /path/to/plist         # Loads the plist as an Agent in my user session
launchctl list                        # Lists Agents in my user session
sudo launchctl load /path/to/plist    # Loads it as a Daemon in the system domain
sudo launchctl list                   # Lists Daemons in the system domain
```

Your package is presumably running its scripts as root, so it will load the job as a Daemon (which is what you want), but it can depend on exactly how the package is configured.

Comment: Thank you again @GordonDavisson. Super useful.

Comment: I just discovered that getting to grips with launchctl also requires knowledge of the nuances of locations as per the documentation:  
  
`~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.  
/Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.  
/Library/LaunchDaemons         System wide daemons provided by the administrator.  
/System/Library/LaunchAgents   OS X Per-user agents.  
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons  OS X System wide daemons.`

Comment: @JamieGarroch-MVP Correct; see my description of the various Library folders [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286571/what-does-mac-os-library-folder-store). But note that recent versions of macOS allow launch agents (and maybe daemons?) to load from places other than the usual Library subfolders. BTW, if this answered your question, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: After realising in [this subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969299/how-to-craft-a-macos-launchd-job-that-can-access-the-home-variable) that the applet which the launchd job runs needs access to the $HOME location, I threw the legacy commands in the trash and opted for the new command as follows: `launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myproduct.plist` Marked as accepted (thanks for the reminder!)