# How to craft a macOS launchd job that can access the $HOME variable

Tags: bash, macos, launchd

I have a PKG installer that installs a launchd job as follows:

File goes here:

/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.myproduct.plist

Post install script activates it as follows:

launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.myproduct.plist

The job runs an applet that needs to get the $HOME variable for the logged in user. When it is manually run from Finder it works as expected but when it runs from launchd the $HOME variable returns a null string.

I've tried moving the job to an agent in these two locations with the same result:

/Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/LaunchAgents

Why is it not working and how can an access the $HOME variable?

**UPDATE 08APR2021**

It seems there are challenges with target domains when using the legacy/deprecated load command. So I rewrote the load command as follows:

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myproduct.plist
```

This obviously assumes that the machine only has one user so it's not very robust.

This is the sanitised plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.myproduct.agent</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>Aqua</string>
    <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Library/Application Support/mycompany/myproduct/agent.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>12</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The agent.app then needs to get the $HOME variable for the active user.

Comment: *"the currently logged in user"*? What if many users are logged in?

Comment: Indeed! That's why I tried moving the job plist to ~/Library/LaunchAgents but it didn't work there either.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you show your `plist` file.

Comment: See the update above @MarkSetchell

Comment: You will probably have better luck on apple.stackexchange.com. The problem is that `launchd` is run by root, not the user that owns ~/Library/LaunchAgents. You would need to get the appropriate user via `launchd` itself, not the environment.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for that pointer. IDKNT existed (as a Win dev)! Using the target domain `gui/501` appears to be working, although I don't understand why based on the comment "launchd is run by root"